# Cannot connect to MySql every time

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

Since upgrading to MySql 5.6.27 I have found that I cannot always connect to the remote MySql database from web servers. It is a hit and miss.

Sometimes the web server will connect to the Mysql Server and other times the connection fails with Debugging errorno 2003. The MySql server is not bound to its address and no there is no firewall blocking. Direct connection from web server to MySql server. Both systems on the same network.

Connection string is

```
$host="host address";
$username="user";
$password="pass";
$dbname="db name";
$mycon=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
```

collecting errors with

```
if (!$mycon) {
echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
exit;
}
```

error given is as follows

> Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 2003 Debugging
>   error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host address' (111)

Has anyone got any ideas what could be causing this. It worked fine on earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

How strange... It seems that the msqli connect string does not like an IP address. If i place the host name in for the mysql server it connects every time. Not sure why that is but it works.